# google web app script - global variable on client side

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a WebApp which takes some values from a google sheet when it is opened. I want to store a global variable so that I do not have to make a call to the server all the time I need that variable.

I checked several questions online, but I am still not able to make it work.

Below is an extract of my code with a tentative to use PropertiesService. However it gives me an error that PropertiesService is not defined.

What is the easiest way to store a variable and use it in different functions from the client (html.file) side?

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yourCallBack2).getPNInfo(body);
    }
  }
  
  function yourCallBack2(pinfo) {
  
  console.log("callback called");
  document.getElementById("ea1").textContent=pinfo[0];
  document.getElementById("in1").value=1;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('TEST', pinfo[0]);
  }
    
  document.getElementById("in1").addEventListener("change",updateQ);
    
  function updateQ(){
    
    var ea = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('TEST');
    console.log(ea);
    var eax = Number(ea);
    var q = document.getElementById("in1").value;
    document.getElementById("ea1").textContent=eax*q;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is store it as a global variable:

```js
var TEST;//Declare global
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(yourCallBack2).getPNInfo(body);
  
  function yourCallBack2(pinfo) {
    console.log("callback called");
    TEST = pinfo[0];//set global
  }
    
  function updateQ(){   
    var ea = TEST;//get global
    console.log(ea);
  }
```

Other ways to persist information would be to use

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [Session/Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

`google.script.run` is a [async call](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). So, `updateQ` might run before `yourCallBack2` and your global variable `TEST` may be `undefined` by then.

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried that method but I was using the wrong syntax. It works now.