# How to set a global JS variable from Code.gs

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm new to working on Google Appscript and Javascript HTML.  I'm working on a webapp that receives an array using google.script.run which works fine, but it seems that I can only access the variable in the receiving function.

My question is,  is there any way that I can receive a variable from Code.gs and set it to a global variable?
HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <div id="variables">
        <input id="state">State</input>
        <input id="equity-spread">Equity</input>
        <input id="age-spread">Age</input>
        <input id="distance">Distance</input>
      </div>
      <div id="letter">
        <button>a</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <button>c</button>
        <button>d</button>
        <button>e</button>
        <button>f</button>
        <button>g</button>
        <button>h</button>
        <button>i</button>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
function formClicked(){
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value
  var equity = document.getElementById("equity-spread").value
  var age = document.getElementById("age-spread").value
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value
  //this function is only to capture and send user input to the server-side Code.gs
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAnalysis).analysis(state,equity,age,distance)
  }

  document.getElementById("letter").addEventListener("click", checkInput);
```

**Code.gs**

```js
function analysis(STATE,EQUITY,AGE,DIST){
  //spreadsheet analysis code here  

  var results = [a,b,c,d]
  return results
```

**index.js**

```js
function displayAnalysis(items){ 
  console.log(items) //this correctly displays the [a,b,c,d] array
  //additional code that modifies the array 
}

function checkInput(e){
  //I created this function because I need the event listener and I couldn't find a way to insert an event listener on the displayAnalysis()
  //I need to access the "items" variable here, but can't figure out how
  
var input = e.target.closest("button").innerHTML 
  console.log(input)
var result = items.indexOf(input) 
  //I can't do indexOf because "items" is undefined
  //I need to evaluate the selected value from the array that was sent over from Code.gs
  var original = items //this produces an undefined
}
```

Essentially, I need the `var items` in both the `displayAnalysis()` and `checkInput` functions to evaluate if the selected value is found in the array sent from Code.gs.

I've tried setting the setting `var _data = items` since I read somewhere that I could "read" the variable publically. I've also rewritten the displayAnalyis function to a global variable like this:

```js
var publicVar = function displayAnalysis(items)
//this also doesn't work
```

Lastly, I also tried getting the event listener and the "items" variable on the same function like this **(this would be the best solution)**:

```js
function formClicked(){
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value
  var equity = document.getElementById("equity-spread").value
  var age = document.getElementById("age-spread").value
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAnalysis).analysis(state,equity,age,distance)
  }

  document.getElementById("letter").addEventListener("click", displayAnalysis);

function displayAnalysis (e,items)
  //console returns "e" as undefined. The first parameter is always defined even if switched
  //this would be the ideal solution because I can receive the "items" and evaluate the "event(e)" together in the same function, but I can't get this to work either.
```

I feel like this is an easy problem to solve but I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want `checkInput`? Your html?

Comment: @TheMaster so that I can take a user selection via click on the html side and compare it to what's being sent from Code GS. I'm using an event listener go capture a clicked value. I tried to receive via a google.script.run and an event listener on the same function but it didn't work.

Comment: *I tried to receive via a google.script.run and an event listener on the same function but it didn't work* That should work. Could  you show that code with debugging details and relavant html?

Comment: @TheMaster just checked and the first parameter simply says "undefined" whether "e" or "items" is in the first position. Any advice?

Comment: Need html. What is `checkInput` attached to ? What is `formClicked` attached to? Why are there two functions?

Comment: @TheMaster HTML added. Added notes to functions

Comment: Kindly add `.addEventListener()` code as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62601014

Comment: @TheMaster thank you. That worked! I declared an  global variable and then set it to equal `items` within the `function displayAnalysis(items)`. I was then able to access the content in other functions. Thank you.